# Creatine New Column Based on JSON List

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following dataset.

```
                     details
USA     [{'country': 'USA', 'city': 'NYC'}]
India   [{'country': 'India', 'city': 'Mumbai'}]
Canada  [{'country': 'Canada', 'city': 'VC'}]
```

I need to create a new column named `city`. I'm trying the following code snippet but finding a TypeError.

```
df['details'] = df['details'].str.strip('[]')
df['city'] = df['details'].map(lambda x: x['city'])
df
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-3f4a312e7420> in <module>
      1 df['details'] = df['details'].str.strip('[]')
----> 2 df['city'] = df['details'].map(lambda x: x['city'])
      3 df

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3907         dtype: object
   3908         """
-> 3909         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3910         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
   3911             self, method="map"

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    935 
    936         # mapper is a function
--> 937         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
    938 
    939         return new_values

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-38-3f4a312e7420> in <lambda>(x)
      1 df['details'] = df['details'].str.strip('[]')
----> 2 df['city'] = df['details'].map(lambda x: x['city'])
      3 df

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I feel the problem I'm facing is with datatypes. What would be the ideal way of doing it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data type of `details` column is of `str` type, not `dict` type. What needs to be done here is that the `details` column first needs to be parsed via `json.loads` and then you can get the value of with `city` key.

You will need to replace single-quotes with double-quotes for it to work.

````
In [5]: df["details"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'", '"'))["city"])
Out[5]:
0    NYC
Name: details, dtype: object```
````

Comment: Hi @faraz-mazhar, thank you for your help. Finding this error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Comment: @Roy You need to replace the single quotes with double quotes as mentioned in the answer. I have updated my codeblock to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

Explode the list and then try to access the city.

```
df['city'] = df['details'].explode().map(lambda x: x['city'])
```

do not strip using : `df['details'] = df['details'].str.strip('[]')` 
Instead use `[explode()]` as shown in above code